# onFling() 2D Animation Issue

Tags: java, android, animation, gesturedetector, onfling

I'm trying to run a very simple 2D animation when I fling an image view. I have 2 activities involved in this.

The GameCanvas

```
@Override 
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY)
    {           
        if(GameWindow.getContext() == null)
            return false;

        if((e1.getY() >= GameWindow.getHeight()) && (e1.getY() <= GameWindow.getBottom()))
        {               
            try
            {                
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) 
                    return false;               
                // right to left slap               
                if((e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) && (Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY))
                {                                   
                    slappingLeft = true;

                    //Animate Slap                  
                    GameWindow.update();                

                    if(!running)
                        running = true;


                }  
                else if ((e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) && (Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY))              
                {       
                    slappingRight = true;

                    //Animate Slap
                    GameWindow.update();

                    if(!running )
                        running = true;
                }
            }                
            catch (Exception e)                 
            {                                   
                //nothing                                   
            }               
        }

        slappingLeft = slappingRight = running = false;
        return true;            
    }
```

And the GameWindow

```
private RefreshHandler mRedrawHandler = new RefreshHandler();

class RefreshHandler extends Handler
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        GameWindow.this.update(); 
        GameWindow.this.invalidate();
    }

    public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
        this.removeMessages(0);
        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
    }
};

public void update() 
{
    //animate slap                  
    if(GameCanvas.slappingLeft)
    {           
        for(int i = 0; i < 500; i+=100)
        {
            GameCanvas.SlapLeft();              
            mRedrawHandler.sleep(100);              
        }
        GameCanvas.SetImage();
        //this.invalidate();
    }
    else if(GameCanvas.slappingRight)                           
    {           
        for(int i = 0; i < 500; i+=100)
        {
            GameCanvas.SlapImage();
            mRedrawHandler.sleep(100);
        }       
        GameCanvas.SetImage();
        //this.invalidate();
    }

}
```

I would greatly appreciate if anyone helps me figure this problem out. I have tried many different approaches to this problem.

I just want to show the SlapImage for half a second, then revert back to the normal image till onFling is called again.

If you would like to see SetImage(), SlapLeft(), and SetImage(), let me know!

Thanks very much in advance!

***EDIT***

GameCanvas is not a Canvas obj. Its an activity that setsContentView(R.layout.game_canvas)

GameWindow is a custom ImageView

Comment: Are you sure that update() is being called? sleep doesn't seem to do anything either. You might look into http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html seems like you are re-inventing the wheel here.

Comment: Yes, update is being called. From the sample Snake game in the anddroid sdk folder, it states that "Create a simple handler that we can use to cause animation to happen. We set ourselves as a target and we can use the sleep() function to cause an update/invalidate to occur at a later date." I was trying to do that.

Comment: but you have commented out sendMessagesDelayed() so its not actually doing anything.

Comment: Yea. Thats right. I re-added it, but i still don't get an animation.

Comment: @schwiz I looked at the link you posted. Im not sure thats a solution for me. What happens is a user picks a person from a list, then I load the images of that person onto the screen. I can't "<item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel0"" in the xml because I won't know what person the user selects before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some consideration, i decided to implement this solution. I think it works fairly well.

I'm still not sure why my previous way didn't work. If anyone would still like to elaborate I would appreciate.

GameCanvas. I created this thread.

```
resetSlap = new Thread()
{
        public void run()
        {           
            while(true)
            {
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    GameWindow.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {                           
                            GameWindow.setImageBitmap(images[0]);
                            GameWindow.postInvalidate();
                        }
                });
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {                               
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                                   
            }
        }
    };
```

Baiscally, every half-second I want to reset the image back to normal

Then in the OnFling I wrote

```
@Override 
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY)
    {           
        if(GameWindow.getContext() == null)
            return false;

        if((e1.getY() >= GameWindow.getHeight()) && (e1.getY() <= GameWindow.getBottom()))
        {       

            try
            {                
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) 
                    return false;               

                // right to left slap               
                if((e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) && 
                        (Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY))
                {                                   
                    slappingLeft = true;

                    //Animate Slap  
                    SlapLeft();
                    SlapSound();
                    if(voice.nextInt(10) < 3)
                    {
                        Voice.start();
                    }

                }  
                // left to right slap
                else if ((e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) && 
                        (Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY))               
                {       
                    slappingRight = true;

                    //Animate Slap
                    SlapImage();
                    SlapSound();
                    if(voice.nextInt(10) < 3)
                    {
                        Voice.start();
                    }
                }
            }                
            catch (Exception e)                 
            {                                   
                //nothing                                   
            }               
        }

        slappingLeft = slappingRight  = false;
        return true;            
    }
```

Basically, if I was slapping left I would call Slap left and wait for the thread to reset and if i was slapping right I would call Slap Right and wait for the thread to reset.

This answer works well for my situation.. I hope this helps :D

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem in your code. Maybe it is influence on the result but I'm not sure. The  problem is that you should use brackets in your if statements because operator && has higher priority then comparison operators. So your code should look in the following way:

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY)
    {           
        if(GameWindow.getContext() == null)
            return false;

        if((e1.getY() >= GameWindow.getHeight()) && (e1.getY() <= GameWindow.getBottom()))
        {               
            try
            {                
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) 
                    return false;               
                // right to left slap               
                if((e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) && (Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY))
                {                                                                                                                   
                    slappingLeft = true;

                    //Animate Slap                  
                    GameWindow.update();                                                                    

                    if(!running)
                        running = true;

                    slappingLeft = false;
                }  
                else if ((e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) && (Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY))              
                {   
                    slappingRight = true;

                    //Animate Slap
                    GameWindow.update();

                    if(!running)
                        running = true;

                    slappingRight = false;

                }
            }                
            catch (Exception e)                 
            {                                   
                //nothing                                   
            }               
        }
        running = false;
        return false;           
    }
```

I don't know if this influence on the logic of your code but it seems to me that yes.

Comment: Hey Yury. I tried out your suggestion, but it has no effect on my code. Even prior to your suggestion, the code was excecuting, but I wasn't and still am not seeing the animation run.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the reason why your code is not executing. This was just my suggestion. Maybe you can post somewhere your project and I'll try to test it.

Comment: How much of it do you need? and idk where I'd post it

Comment: Is it huge? Can you take only the part of the project and create a new one which I can test? Just then create a chat with me and we'll deal about how you can post it.